# Oracle - Concatenating a string with a variable in equality clause

Tags: string, oracle, plsql, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a string with a variable in the oracle where/= clause and am getting "invalid operator" I know this must be something simple, but I'm missing the mark somewhere:

```
select * form test_table where path = "'/'||upper(&&usr)||'/forms/test_stuff.xml'"
```

> Error: invalid identifier.pl/sql statement ignored.

Comment: The problem is your double quotes. Remove them. Then, what tool are you using? Does this tool consider `&&` an indicator for a variable? Otherwise you could to try a bind variable preceded with a colon: `select * form test_table where path = '/' || upper(:usr) || '/forms/test_stuff.xml'`.

Comment: using sqlplus and executing script from the command line. and no the &&usr is a variable that is passed to the script

Comment: And does it work when you remove the double quotes?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I set the value as a variable and then set it up as above and it worked.

Comment: If you are using SQL\*Plus, it would help if you edit your post and add a minimal version of the script.

Comment: Say it prompts for the value of `&&usr` and you supply `banana`.  It then runs `select * from test_table where path = "'/'||upper(banana)||'/forms/test_stuff.xml'"`, which is invalid unless `test_table` has a column named `"'/'||upper(&&usr)||'/forms/test_stuff.xml'"`. This seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is **"&&"** operator, in oracle we cannot create any column which is start from &&.
And in your query **"&&USR"** consider as a column which is wrong.